# How to calculate frequency of each number and display results as a table

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numbers:

```
x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]
```

Now I want to calculate frequency of each number and display results as a table using, e.g. [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate).

I calculate frequencies this way:

```
import collections

c = collections.Counter(x)
count_sum = sum(c.values())

for key,value in c.iteritems():
  print str(key) + " - " + str(float(value) / count_sum)
```

I don't know how to create an array of  and pass it to `tabulate`. The ideal solution would be to use `numpy`.

Comment: `print(tabulate([[val,val/count_sum] for key,val in c.iteritems()]))` .... why do you need to use `numpy`?

Comment: @Jose Ricardo Bustos M.: Because it looks like the simplest input of tabulate, But I'm not sure. What is the simplest solution?

Comment: @Jose Ricardo Bustos M.: I checked your solution, but it gives 0 as a frequency for all numbers. It should be float(val)/count_sum

Comment: @Jose Ricardo Bustos M.: Also, I want each value to be displayed only once.

Comment: It gives 0 because he probably tried it on Python 3. For Python 2, use `float(val)/count_sum` instead of `val/count_sum`, otherwise all ratios will be floored to 0.

Comment: @JonasL: Thanks. But the biggest problem is that values are repeated: 1: 0.03125, 1:0.03125, 8: 0.25

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments of Jose Ricardo Bustos M. and JonasL:

The answer for Python 2.8 is:

```
print(tabulate([[key,float(val)/count_sum] for key,val in c.iteritems()]))
```

To get numbers from x, it is necessary to use `key`, while `val` defines absolute frequency (count) of a number.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, using `numpy` and `tabulate`.  The counts of the values are computed using [`numpy.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html).

```
In [42]: import numpy as np

In [43]: from tabulate import tabulate

In [44]: x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]

In [45]: values, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)

In [46]: values
Out[46]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [47]: counts
Out[47]: array([8, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 8, 2, 2])

In [48]: print tabulate([values, counts/float(counts.sum())])
----  -------  -------  -----  -------  -------  ----  ------  ------
1     2        3        4      5        6        7     8       9
0.25  0.09375  0.03125  0.125  0.03125  0.09375  0.25  0.0625  0.0625
----  -------  -------  -----  -------  -------  ----  ------  ------
```